# Concatenate column + subselect, even when subselect returns no results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I concatenate a column and a subselect, even when this subselect returns no results?

On the dumb example bellow, when the subselect returns no results, the result returns NULL, even when the `Column_a` is not null.

```
select a.Column_a + 
    (select top 1 b.Column_b from Table_b b where b.Id_Table_a = a.Id)
from Table_a a
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: You need something like [`ISNULL`](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-system-functions/sql-server-isnull-function/) to wrap your subquery.

Comment: You could use ISNULL, COALESCE, CONCAT or STRING_AGG. Basically anything that will turn your NULL into an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL SERVER if you concanate or add two string together where one string is NULL, the result returns NULL as below-

```
SELECT 'Test' + NULL
-- The output is NULL
```

So you have to handle NULL as below-

```
SELECT 'Test' + ISNULL( NULL,'')
-- This will return 'Test'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by adding `isnull()`:

```
select a.Column_a + 
    isnull((select top 1 b.Column_b from Table_b b where b.Id_Table_a = a.Id), '')
from Table_a a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL (assuming all values are strings):

```
select a.Column_a + 
    ISNULL((select top 1 b.Column_b from Table_b b where b.Id_Table_a = a.Id),'')
from Table_a a
```